# There are no censored observations in my survival model. Is this a problem?

Tags: survival, cox-model, censoring, kaplan-meier

I have time-to-event data (survival analysis). All animals experienced the event during the study period, i.e. there are no censored observations. Does this affect the validity of survival models (Kaplan-Meier or Cox Proportional Hazard)?

Answer (score 7):

No. This just makes the estimation easier because you have complete data. Complete data gives more information than a data set that has some right-censored observations.